# Sort by number in a text.combine field

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Dear Power Bi Community,
I have an issue with the group by function where the combined values are combination of 2 fields :
Field 1 = numbers
Field 2 = text

I’ve used the following formula to group rows :
= Table.Group(#"customized column", {"FactorA", "FactorB"}, {{"Combined value", each Text.Combine((List.Sort( [Field1 & Field2], Order.Ascending),"#(lf)"), type nullable text}})

with this formula, rows into each combined value is sorted but as following :
1 xxxx
10 xxxx
2 xxxx
while I’m looking for an order as :
1 xxxx
2 xxxx
10 xxxx
Any ideas to help with are more than welcome !
Many thanks in advance for your help !
Regards,

Comment: you can convert the Field 1 to text in format "00"

Comment: ``Number.ToText( [Field1], "00" )``

Comment: Please add sample data in text format.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing a part, but why not just sort then combine? Why do you need the group

```
let #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(Source,{{"Field1", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Sorted Rows", {{"Field1", type text}}, "en-US"),{"Field1", "Field2"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.None),"Combined")
in #"Merged Columns"
```

[image]